# docker restarts, and want to find the reason

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I see docker containers restarts after the host receives huge network requests spike.

(I'm running ECS on ec2 instance)

I guess network requests spike somehow makes the instance unstable and somehow docker container decides to restart.

What logs should I look for to narrow down what causes the container restart?

Comment: container is running in EC2 instance or you are using ECS  ?

Comment: yes @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: If ECS events logs does not help out then you can check `cd /var/log/ecs/RESTART_DATE_LOG` or `tail -v /var/log/docker`  also verify there is no such restriction  on task defintion level

Comment: did you check log on task_defination ?